# Eliminating empty columns from rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a postgresql database where I want to compare the data in two tables, A and B.  Eventually, I'd like to create a (probably materialized) view.  The two tables have identical structure (columns and data types).  Table A contains static baseline information.  Table B contains the same columns; however, it is dynamic, and the columns are empty unless there is changed data.  I want to be able to show the data from table A alongside the data from table B when there is data in table B.  This query works:

```
SELECT A.c1, B.c1, A.c2, B.c2, A.c3, B.c3, A.c4, B.c4
FROM A
INNER JOIN B on
A.c1 = B.c1;
```

However, if a column in table B is empty (NULL), I don't need the data from that column from table A.  I can take care of that when I present the table view to the user, but is there a way to take care of eliminating that data in the SQL up front? Alternatively, would I be better off taking care of this when I load the data that goes into table B?

Thanks--

Al

Comment: Not really.  A SQL query has pre-defined columns.  The columns in the result set are not data-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CASE clauses to return nulls for the A.c2, A.c3... columns if the corresponding columns are null. Note this solution is specific to PostgreSQL.

```sql
    SELECT CASE WHEN B.c2 IS NOT NULL THEN A.c2 ELSE NULL END AS ref_c2, B.c2,
```

A complete query with A as ref and B as data, with a row id field would be

```sql
    -- For PostgreSQL
    SELECT data.id, ref.c1, data.c1,
       CASE WHEN data.c2 IS NOT NULL THEN ref.c2 ELSE NULL END AS ref_c2, data.c2,
       CASE WHEN data.c3 IS NOT NULL THEN ref.c3 ELSE NULL END AS ref_c3, data.c3,
       CASE WHEN data.c4 IS NOT NULL THEN ref.c4 ELSE NULL END AS ref_c4, data.c4
      FROM ref
      INNER JOIN data on
      ref.c1 = data.c1;
```

If you are going to end up pulling all the data from table A multiple times in this query then consider separating your queries and do the join client side. 
In the client language Copy table A into a map keyed on c1 then Query from table B and only output the values of A when there are non null values from B based on B.c1. This will reduce memory use on both server and client sides depending on your data since you only pull and store the data from A once. If the query basically is your output and you don't need to optimize for memory, the above sql solution is fine.

Comment: Or load b rows only where at least one col is not null and from that backjoin A :-)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe . I added THEN to the CASE clause fixing a problem in the original answer and tested the solution. coalesce is for replacing NULL with data where as the question is closer to how to replace data with NULL. I also added note that this is a solution for PostgreSQL as per OP, not a general SQL solution. Also I tested